# checkbox always gives last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to get the Firstname and last name from the box you select. The problem is that it only gives me the last value, it doesn't matter which box you select.

```
for (var i = 0; i<obj.length; i++) {
    firstname = obj[i].Firstname;
    lastname = obj[i].Lastname;

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "name";
    checkbox.value = "value";
    checkbox.id = "id";

    var divElement = document.createElement("div");  

    divElement.id = "myDiv";  
    divElement.className = "myDivClass";  
    divElement.style.border = "1px solid black";

    var userPar= document.createElement("p"); 

    userPar.innerHTML = firstname + " " +  lastname;
    document.getElementById("users").appendChild(divElement);  
    divElement.appendChild(userPar);
    divElement.appendChild(checkbox);
}

function save() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            var first = firstname;
            var last = lastname;
            console.log(firstname);
            console.log(lastname);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: May I know, what is `obj`?

Comment: Start by moving `function save(){...` outside your loop.

Comment: In your save function you are getting the value of `firstName` and `lastName` which you set in the loop (i.e. when the loop ends, they have the values of the last item)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
for (var i = 0; i<obj.length; i++) {
    firstname = obj[i].Firstname;
    lastname = obj[i].Lastname;

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "name";
    checkbox.value = "value";
    checkbox.id = "id" + i;

    var divElement = document.createElement("div");  

    divElement.id = "myDiv" + i;  
    divElement.className = "myDivClass";  
    divElement.style.border = "1px solid black";

    var userPar= document.createElement("p"); 

    userPar.innerHTML = firstname + " " +  lastname;
    document.getElementById("users").appendChild(divElement);  
    divElement.appendChild(userPar);
    divElement.appendChild(checkbox);
}

function save() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (index, val) {
        if ($(val).is("checked")) {

            var RawText = $(val).parent().find("p").text();
            var first = RawText.split(" ")[0];
            var last = RawText.split(" ")[1];
            console.log(firstname);
            console.log(lastname);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the right names are their. But the value in console.log isn't the same. Still only the last value is given.

Comment: @user3644686 jsfiddle is totally messed up. add jquery library from references available left side of the page and you will have to add code of firstlastname.js in jsfiddle

Comment: I don't know actually how this works but i added jquery libary and the javascript code is all the code below. http://jsfiddle.net/mF89k/5/